# Open file in android using intent

Tags: android, email, android-intent, attachment

After using a intent to cause my app to launch from the email application, how do I open the file that caused the launch? Normally I just use

```
fis = openFileInput("test.txt");
```

But since its just launching the application from a intent I don't know the name. I am assuming it will have something to do with acquiring the URI. I am launching the app using

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
   <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.xls" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get InputStream for the file you could use the code like this in your Activity's `onCreate()` method:

```
Uri dataUri = getIntent().getData();
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
InputStream input = cr.openInputStream(dataUri);
//input.read() or whatever you want...
```